# Question on integral theory

Tags: self-learning

When does basic integral theory that you learn in 
a first year real analysis course lead to measure 
theory 
What techniques.. do I need to make the transition 
less painful 
Measure theory seems much more abstract.

Comment: It doesn't really, at least not in a natural way. Perhaps a less abstract approach would be to consider measure theory from a probability perspective, how to define events in a manner that is consistent.

Comment: Not sure what is painful about measure theory. It seems like a relatively straightforward generalization of interval lengths and areas bounded by curves.  The next good example to consider, I suppose, is the example of center of mass of a rod with nonconstant density.